# Repeating the subject in a subordinate sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Just a short while ago I edited [a question published on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124470/is-there-an-english-dictionary-that-distinguishes-words-as-either-abstract-or-co)<sup>(1)</sup> and, doing this, I added the following paragraph:

> The words that express the tangible and visible things of our experience, such as sand or sea, are all nouns, as **they are** those expressing intangibles such as love or idealism.

Is it proper English "as **they are** those expressing intangibles such as love or idealism"?

I'm not sure if using **they are** there is correct and, when editing, other possibilities that came to my mind were:

- "as those expressing intangibles such as love or idealism";
- "as those expressing intangibles, such as love or idealism, are".

What is the rule governing the way in which that sentence can be correctly written? And what is the correct version?

<sup>(1) After Stoney's comment I edited again the original question in order to remove the grammaatical error.</sup>

Comment: The first pronoun is redundant with the second, and misplaced. What you want is "as are those expressing..."

Comment: I think you mean “just a few minutes ago” and “I *noticed* the following”.

Comment: @Stoney, thanks, but is "are those" a case in which sebject and verb are inverted, or "those" doesn't work as subject here?

Comment: @Tyler, I edited the question!

Comment: @ Carlo_R.: Strange. I edited it too (changing *few times* to *short while*). I can see my edit, but not yours. I suspect the system doesn't record *the fact of* edits made by the OP very soon after the original posting. I'm guessing it just shows the text in its final form where you're just "tidying up" within timeframes that are effectively part of the original posting.

Comment: @Fumble, the question to which I was referring to in  "I edited the question!" is the question of which I'm speaking in this question. The fact is that Tyler suggested me to replace "added" with "noticed", but I really "added" that paragraph to the EL&U question--i.e., it was not already written when I edited that question, so I did not notice anything.

Comment: @FumbleFingers For the record, for five minutes after any post's text changes (either the OP's initial post, or any edit) if the same person goes back and changes it, it's recorded as part of the same edit. The interim edit is not recorded.

Comment: (Also Carlo, can we have a link to the ELU question?)

Comment: @Wendi, I added the link, but do you have some explanation on the why that question has five downvotes? To me it seems not so bad and I greatly improved it.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Downvotes are probably based on the [original revision](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/124470/1), but I can't be sure; I'm not an ELU mod :)

Comment: The inversion is demanded for by the "weight" of the subject. Colloquially we would say "They are all nouns, as those are". Formally we may also say "...as are those". But in any register you pretty much **have to** say "... as are those which are qualified by a long string of words", because that's just too long to postpone your verb and expect people to remember where the clause started. In any case, you don't want "as they are those", which is two subjects for one verb.

Answer (score 2):

I think the relevant "rule" is that subject normally precedes verb in English. But in OP's example the subject is quite a long noun phrase, so putting ***are*** at the end is awkward, to say the least. Thus,...

> 1: Most Syrians are law-abiding folk, as we are
>    2: Most Syrians are law-abiding folk, as are we who debate whether US intervention would be legal.

But that may not be the whole story. The basic construction *X is [something], **as is** Y* is something of a "set format", so even in my example #1 above, ***as are*** we would be perfectly normal phrasing. Overall though, I'd say this is an aspect of grammar that owes more to the past than to the present or future.

Answer (score 1):

In the question, "they are" is incorrect; native speakers would omit "they". In fact, including "they" makes the sentence very difficult to decipher, so this isn't a fine point; it's a gross error. (Your example without "they" but with "are" at the end is fine, though.)

But *why* is it a gross error? To understand that, we need to undo the heavy ellipsis that otherwise makes the sentence so elegant. I'll put brackets where I changed things.

"The words that express the tangible and visible things of our experience, such as sand or sea, are all nouns, [and] those words expressing intangibles such as love or idealism [are nouns]."

The use of "as" lets you omit the complement "noun". That gets us to:

"The words that express the tangible and visible things of our experience, such as sand or sea, are all nouns, as those words expressing intangibles such as love or idealism [are]."

If this were any verb besides "to be" that "[are]" would be "[do]" by the way.

Then, since English allows verb fronting under most circumstances we end up with:

"The words that express the tangible and visible things of our experience, such as sand or sea, are all nouns, as are those words expressing intangibles such as love or idealism."

The fronting "feels" better in this case, I think, because otherwise the "are" is too far away.

Hope all that helps a bit.

Comment: Greg, excellent answer in its articulation, +1.